# Consuming Web Services with C# on Compact Framework: Unmarshalling Error

Tags: c#, soap, https, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I'm having difficulties on consuming a web service using a Windows Mobile PDA. I'm using C#, VS2008, Compact framework. I have a WSDL address that I have used to "Add web reference...", then I have access to "Mywebservice" on the code. My current code is:

```
using (myWebService ws = new myWebService()) {
    try {                    
        ws.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "12345678");       
        ws.Url = "https://webservice_endpoint_address";             
        outputArgs = ws.myWebServiceMethod(inputArgs);                    
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

To solve some certificate problems I'm using:

```
public class TrustAllCertificatePolicy : System.Net.ICertificatePolicy
{
    public TrustAllCertificatePolicy()
    { }

    public bool CheckValidationResult(System.Net.ServicePoint sp, X509Certificate cert, System.Net.WebRequest req, int problem)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And on Form.Activated include

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.CertificatePolicy = new TrustAllCertificatePolicy();
```

When I try to consume the web service I'm getting the following error: "System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderException: Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element (uri:"http://com.service.........", ...)

I have seen some references to using "System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute" vs "System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapRPCMethodAttribute" but I'm not sure if it is really this and I don't know how to change it for testing.

Is there a way to inspect the messages that are being created?

Many thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: You need to configure transport layer security. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms729700(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Nurzhan Thanks for your edit! Changing the tags is always important. Be sure to mention it in your edit message.